# Access SQL/Macros

Tags: sql, database, ms-access-2013

I need to check for null values in a column of an imported Excel document and if its null let the user know with a msg box.  I created an if statement in the Macro.

```
if IsNull([Todays Resources].[Department]) then
Message Box
"Null Field, enter data"
```

The if statement is entered after the import and create table section of the Macro.  It is returning an error "Microsoft Access cannont find the name 'Todays Resources' you entered in the expression." Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Are you checking for entire column at a time in the excel??you can loop through and check !!!!

Comment: Yes I am checking the entire column.

Comment: The Column is "Department", Table name "Todays Resources"

Comment: I don't understand,you checking Null value in excel file?? or in microsoft access??

Comment: You can query like 'search count(col) from table_name where col=NULL' if query returns more than one row ..you can show that in a messagebox ...if you are working in excel with macros ..try checking for null cell by looping through the columns if found show ur message bx..hope this helps....

Comment: I am importing an excel file via Macro, I then need to check that a column on that file has no null values.  If it does have a null value, I need to have a message box populate.

Comment: Select your table and write the code as  if IsNull([Department]) then
Message Box
"Null Field, enter data"